# Migrating script from Spreadsheet to Site

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a few scripts in various spreadsheets I'd like to 'migrate' to a site page.
I know I'll need to do some re-work, but I'd like to know if there's  method besides 'Copy/Paste'.

Anyone have any 'best practices' to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, copy 'n paste **was** the only way to go, and is still probably the solution for you. But there's some shiny new features, like having a standalone script or sharing it as a library that might suit you better.

Take a look at the recent [release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes) and [blog posts](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/big-updates-for-apps-script.html).

Comment: Thanks Herique, I have the feeling I'll be doing a fair amount of rework.  My script currently launch from a spreadsheet menu and update tabs on the existing spreadsheet.  I plan on moving the logic to a site and then create specific spreadsheets for each user session.  They want the output in spreadsheets for manual manipulation. 
I haven't gotten a handle on the library or standalone script yet, but my gut is that's where I need to go for code control & distribution.

Thanks !